# New form disappear after creation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing a problem with form show. I have a main form where I have my GUI and I choose an option that creates an instance of a form. For example in my main form I have:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

The problem is that the form shows for about 1-2 secs and then goes behind the main form.

I tried some instructions in the main form below `f2.Show()` command like

```
f2.BringtoFront();
this.SendtoBack();
```

Also I added commands to the new form (`Form2`) load method:

```
this.BringtoFront();
this.Activate();
this.Focus();
```

Nothing of the above commands seems to be a solution for this. Only when I use `f2.ShowDialog();` instruction in my main form but I don't want to do that because I need immediate access to both of these forms at the same time.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: In which method are you writing f2.Show()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your second form to never go behind your main form then pass the owner in the overload of [Show method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts the owner parameter

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 f2.Show(this);   // Assuming this code runs inside the main form
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove or change it to comment **this.SendtoBack();** :

```
f2.BringtoFront();
//this.SendtoBack();
```

it'll be OK!